# How to updade my page after call an action in DART?

Tags: flutter, dart, action, reload

I'm need to update my page after call an action and i'm not having been able to do it until now.

Here is one example of what i need:

```
onTap(){
// my logic
}

SOMEHOW UPDATE THE PAGE (RELOAD)


if (p.situacao == "R" && tA == "P") {
              Alert(
                context: context,
                type: AlertType.warning,
                title: "${p.num}?",
                buttons: [
                  DialogButton(
                    child: Text(
                      "Sim",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () async {
                      APt.aPt();
                      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));
                      await Confirmacao(context);
                    },
                    color: Color(0xFF0578be),
                  ),
                  DialogButton(
                    child: Text(
                      "Não",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                    color: Color(0xFF0578be),
                  )
                ],
              ).show();
            }
```

I need reload the content.

Comment: Perfect job for a State Management tool, like Provider or RiverPod or Cubit... choose your favorite.  Then, you can have the page depend on updates to your data.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz is it not killing an ant with a hammer? If the goal is only to refresh the page he can use a simple setState call in a stateful widget

Comment: It wasn't clear the logic was within the same widget.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can Update UI using just call setState(() {}) 

 onTap(){

    setState(() {});

    }
```

But if you want reload api call then that will be different case.

Comment: Adding more context: i have an web api that provide me information that i load on my page. But when i call some action, i need show to the user the new status os this information. So i think is the case. You could please show me how?

Comment: If you want to update the information base on some action which was shown from API call ?

Comment: Yes, how could i do that?

Comment: can you share some snippet? Then i can help you perfectly.

Comment: Yes, sure, i've posted in the question. THank you!